# Why are my style.css updates reflected only when performing a hard refresh, reverting to a previous version when refreshing afterwards?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, caching, web

Long title, sorry. Anyway:

I've got a WordPress site with a custom theme and its child theme. For a while, updating the child theme's style.css would produce results as expected - a refresh (or hard-refresh) of the website, and it would work from then on out.

Now, however, my updates are only reflected when I hard-refresh a certain page. If I then refresh the same page, or navigate to a different page on which the changes should be applied, the changes are reverted and the old style.css file is called instead.

I am using, and have tried purging all the caches available through the "W3 Total Cache" plugin. I have tried disabling "W3 Total Cache" entirely and installing the "Style.css Load Last Version" plugin, which as far as I know is using [this trick](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/prevent-css-caching/) to always call for the latest style.css file. I've tried visiting the page using incognito mode. In all cases, the behavior is the same - hard refresh works as a one-time deal, either refreshing the same page or navigating to different parts of the site which should be effected results in the browser calling for an older style.css file version and the changes are reverted.

Long test, sorry :) Anyway, I would love some feedback on this issue as its driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which method are you using to load your child-theme's css file??
If you are using a link to include your child css as

```
<link rel="" ..............> then try appending the version at the end of you file name 

<link rel="stylesheed"...... href="your_child_style.css?v-=1.10"> where ?v=1.10 is the version number. Every time you update your css increase the version number(In case you don't want to change the version every time i suggest you use the php time() function to generate a unique number eveytime the css is loaded)
```

If your css file is loaded automatically then make sure you have version decalared in you css file as

```
/*
Theme Name: yourchildtheme
Version: 1.2
```

*/

Try to change the version and it will work just fine.
Good luck

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_child_theme_scripts' );
function my_child_theme_scripts() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-theme-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for responding! The CSS file is loaded automatically. To make sure I wasn't missing anything, I changed the version number to 10.00. After purging caches etc., I refreshed and the website still did not show the relevant changes. I manually edited the HTTP header of the file and appended the correct version number to the end of the style.css file, and the changes took place. Upon refreshing the page, they again reverted back. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please inspect the site and see if your style.css is load more than once !! just a hunch.. 
And please do check the version appended to the loaded style.css also

Comment: Here is the website address: www.schockenplus.com. Inspecting the <head> shows that the style.css is only loaded once, but amongst other style sheets needed for the rest of the site (which should not contain conflicting code). Upon refreshing the page, the style.css version that is being loaded is 4.5.2, and if I manually change that to 10.00 everything works. I just can't figure out why its pulling that specific stylesheet instead of the new one.

Comment: Try
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_child_theme_scripts' );
function my_child_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-theme-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css?v=1.20' );
}

Comment: OK, so, I took a look at the parent theme's functions.php file and saw this in there:

function nectar_main_styles() { wp_register_style("main-styles", get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/style.css", '', '4.5.2'); 
wp_enqueue_style('main-styles');

What I did was comment out the version number as follows:

wp_register_style("main-styles", get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/style.css");//, '', '4.5.2');

And, it seems to work. Is there a disadvantage in doing it this way as opposed to what you wrote?

Comment: No it's the same process. Glad it worked. If same problem persist in future then try to append some random number like time() instead of fixed version as 4.5.2.